# Order of expression elements evaluation in SSRS 2008 - is it wrong?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

The fiscal year of my client begins in November.
I used the following expression to sort a Fiscal Month category:

```
=Month(
    DateAdd(
        DateInterval.Month,
        -10,
        CDate(
            Fields!FiscalMonth.Value + ", 01 1900"
        )
    )
)
```

and it worked fine until I had to add previous year end value to the category. I thought that sorting that would be trivial with the expression like this:

```
=Iif(
    Fields!FiscalMonth.Value = "YearEnd",
    0,
    Month(
        DateAdd(
            DateInterval.Month,
            -10,
            CDate(
                Fields!FiscalMonth.Value + ", 01 1900"
            )
        )
    )
)
```

but it is throwing an error `Conversion from string "YearEnd, 01 1900" to type 'Date' is not valid` on the `YearEnd` value. That should not be possible, as `Iif` should protect its 2nd parameter. How else can I ensure that 'YearEnd' is assigned 0 sort order?

**UPDATE:**

The error occurs even with the following expression:

```
=Iif(
    Fields!FiscalMonth.Value = "YearEnd",
    0,
    CDate(
        Fields!FiscalMonth.Value + ", 01 1900"
    )
)
```

but does not occur with

```
=Iif(
    Fields!FiscalMonth.Value = "YearEnd",
    0,
    Fields!FiscalMonth.Value + ", 01 1900"
)
```

To me it sounds like SSRS evaluates `CDate()` before it evaluated `Iif()` 1st argument. A bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
=Iif(
    Fields!FiscalMonth.Value = "YearEnd",
    0,
    Month(
        DateAdd(
            DateInterval.Month,
            -10,
            CDate(
                Iif(Fields!FiscalMonth.Value = "YearEnd", "November", Fields!fiscalmonth.Value) + ", 01 1900"
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Does anyone know how can I scream at Microsoft: **DO NOT EVALUATE Iif's 2ND PARAMETER IF THE 1ST PARAMETER EVALUATES TO 'FALSE' AND DO NOT EVALUATE THE 3D PARAMETER IF THE 1ST PARAMETER EVALUATES TO 'TRUE'???**

Comment: I'm trying hard not to downvote this for the loud shouting. And there's no point screaming at them: this is a documented behaviour of the `iif()` function. It's quite easy to add a custom function that short-circuits, as shown in the duplicate (one of many possible dupes) I flagged up above.